# In VS Studio Code, the fish terminal does not apply fish config, but outside VS Code, in the classic terminal, the config is well applied

Tags: visual-studio-code, fish

In my mac, when I open the classic terminal, the fish terminal is well launched and the config is well applied (with colors, history etc). But when I use the VS code terminal, the fish terminal is launched, but the fish config is not applied : the colors, history, alias etc are not available.

I tried the source command in the VS Code integrated terminal:

```
source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Comment: possibly related discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139400

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a login-related issue? Running `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), I see this:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        ...
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        ...
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        ...
```

Notably, the Linux default terminal profile setting doesn't pass `-l`, but the OSX profile does.

If you're on macOS, then try checking if you've overridden the fish terminal profile in a way that doesn't pass `-l`.

If you're on Linux and that's the issue, I *think* you can work around it by just redefining the terminal profile in your user settings.json, adding the `-l` flag (you can copy from the OSX terminal profile for fish).